# Use Collectors to convert List to Map of Objects - Java

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream, collectors

How do I use Collectors in order to convert a list of DAOs, to a `Map<String, List<Pojo>>`

daoList looks something like this:

```
[0] : id = "34234", team = "gools", name = "bob", type = "old"
[1] : id = "23423", team = "fool" , name = "sam", type = "new"
[2] : id = "34342", team = "gools" , name = "dan", type = "new"
```

I want to groupBy 'team' attribute and have a list for each team, as follows:

```
"gools":
       ["id": 34234, "name": "bob", "type": "old"],
       ["id": 34342, "name": "dan", "type": "new"]

"fool":
       ["id": 23423, "name": "sam", "type": "new"]
```

Pojo looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Pojo{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

This is how I'm trying to do that, obviously the wrong way:

```
public Team groupedByTeams(List<? extends GenericDAO> daoList)
    {

        Map<String, List<Pojo>> teamMap= daoList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GenericDAO::getTeam))
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your current collector - `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GenericDAO::getTeam))` - is generating a `Map<String,List<? extends GenericDAO>>`.

In order to generate a `Map<String, List<Pojo>>`, you have to convert your `GenericDAO` instances into `Pojo` instances by chaining a `Collectors.mapping()` collector to the `Collectors.groupingBy()` collector:

```
Map<String, List<Pojo>> teamMap = 
    daoList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GenericDAO::getTeam,
                                          Collectors.mapping (dao -> new Pojo(...),
                                                              Collectors.toList())));
```

This is assuming you have some `Pojo` constructor that receives a `GenericDAO` instance or relevant `GenericDAO` properties.

Answer (score 7):

Use `mapping` as:

```
public Map<String, List<Team>> groupedByTeams(List<? extends GenericDAO> daoList) {
    Map<String, List<Team>> teamMap = daoList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GenericDAO::getTeam,
                    Collectors.mapping(this::convertGenericDaoToTeam, Collectors.toList())));
    return teamMap;
}
```

where a conversion such as `convertGenericDaoToTeam` could be possibly like:

```
Team convertGenericDaoToTeam(GenericDAO genericDAO) {
    return new Team(genericDAO.getId(), genericDAO.getName(), genericDAO.getType());
}
```